# Map values not saving to sobject

Tags: apex

In contact lastName is having duplicate values & I am removing the duplicates from the list, storing it inside a map and updating the map values to sobject. Here's the code, but when I save the updated values to sobject they aren't getting saved. Pls let me know how to go about this fix.

```
List<Contact> conList=new List<Contact>([select Id,LastName,Email
                                        from contact 
                                         where LastName LIKE '%testname%']);

Map<String,contact> conMap=new Map<String,contact>();
for(contact con:conList)
{   
    conMap.put(con.LastName,con);
}

Database.Update(conMap.values());
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! I've updated the formatting for your question to make it easier to read, but I'm still not sure what you expect to be happening (you aren't updating any fields in the records you're querying). Can you go into more detail about what you're trying to accomplish? About my best guess as to what you're trying to accomplish is de-duplication of contacts (there are better ways to do this), but it's always better to hear exact details from the person asking the question than it is to guess at what someone means.

Comment: @derek, is my approach right? just wanted to get rid of duplicate lastname records and store the latest in the contact.If there are other ways to accomplish the above then pls do let me know

Comment: I don't know if the approach you're taking is correct _because I don't completely understand what, exactly, you're trying to accomplish_. I'd encourage you to go into more detail about what you're trying to do. Editing your question to give us an example scenario (I start with this set of data/records, and I want to end with this different set of data/records) would probably help too.

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't address your code but it does address your business problem.

You should look into the platform's built-in duplicate management features rather than building something from scratch. This will allow you to identify and manage duplicate records as well as cleanup duplicates that are already in the system without writing any code.

**Details from Trailhead**

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/sales_admin_duplicate_management

**Org Wide Duplicate cleanup resources**

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=manage_duplicates_globally.htm&type=5

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you're trying to *get rid of duplicates*, which implies the notion of *deletion*. You can't "update" a record into oblivion, you need to "delete" it, instead. That would look like this:

```
Set<String> lastNames = new Set<String>();
Contact[] recordsToDelete = new Contact[0];
for(Contact record: [SELECT LastName FROM Contact WHERE LastName LIKE '%testname%']) {
  if(!lastNames.add(record.LastName.toLowerCase()) {
    recordsToDelete.add(record);
  }
}
delete recordsToDelete;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Contact> conList=new List<Contact>([select Id,LastName,Email
                                        from contact 
                                         where LastName LIKE '%abc%']);
Map<String,contact> conMap=new Map<String,contact>();
List<Contact> conDelete = new List<Contact>();
for(contact conData:conList)
{   
    if(!conMap.containskey(conData.LastName)){
        conMap.put(conData.LastName,conData);
    }else{
        conDelete.add(conData);
    }
}
delete conDelete;
```